Open Build Service: How to include vendored dependencies as an extra source when building for debian
I'm currently trying to setup Open Build Service for my program. I've successfully setup the RPM version of the package using a .spec file.
My project is a rust project, for the RPM version, I have an OBS service that vendors all of the dependencies for my program in a vendor.tar.zst and within the spec file I include it as an additional source, and during the build I simply unpack it.
However, I cannot seem to find any documentation or examples which do the same but in Debian.
Here's my _service file:
<services>
    <service name="tar_scm" mode="manual">
        <param name="revision">main</param>
        <param name="url">https://github.com/TheAlexDev23/power-options.git</param>
        <param name="scm">git</param>
        <param name="extract">dist/obs/power-options-daemon.dsc</param>
        <param name="extract">dist/obs/power-options-daemon.spec</param>
        <param name="extract">dist/obs/debian.changelog</param>
        <param name="extract">dist/obs/debian.compat</param>
        <param name="extract">dist/obs/debian.control</param>
        <param name="extract">dist/obs/debian.postinst</param>
        <param name="extract">dist/obs/debian.postrm</param>
        <param name="extract">dist/obs/debian.rules</param>
    </service>
    <service name="recompress" mode="manual">
      <param name="compression">gz</param>
      <param name="file">*.tar</param>
    </service>
    <service name="cargo_vendor" mode="manual">
        <!-- <param name="src">power-options-1.1.0.tar.zst</param> -->
        <param name="src">power-options</param>
        <param name="update">true</param>
    </service>
    <service name="set_version" mode="manual"/>
</services>

Within the .spec file, I simply reference 2 sources:
Source0:   power-options-%{version}.tar.gz
Source1:   vendor.tar.zst

And then extract the vendored dependencies in the build process:
tar -xf %{_sourcedir}/vendor.tar.zst --directory .

My package-name.dsc file looks like this:
Format: 1.0
Source: power-options-daemon
Version: 1728215162.64c0a52
Binary: build
Maintainer: Alexander Karpukhin <thealexdev23@gmail.com>
Architecture: all
Standards-Version: 3.7.2
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 4), cargo

And debian.control:
Source: power-options-daemon
Section: admin
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Alexander Karpukhin <thealexdev23@gmail.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 5), cargo
Standards-Version: 3.7.2
Homepage: https://github.com/thealexdev23/power-options

Package: power-options-daemon
Architecture: any
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}, acpid, pciutils, usbutils, yad
Recommends: brightnessctl, net-tools, xorg-xrandr, xorg-xset, xautolock
Description: The core daemon for Power Options, a blazingly fast power management solution.

